# Calling func with CGFloat variable

Tags: ios, swift, variables, func

I am trying to call a func with a CGFloat variable with the code below, but it does not go to the position I want. May I know what's the problem with it?

```
var triggerTime = (Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC) * 10)
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, triggerTime), dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.AnswerUp(1500)


func AnswerUp (upValue: CGFloat){
    Answer1.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Left
    Answer2.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Left
    Answer3.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Left
    Answer4.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Left



    self.AnswerView.frame = CGRectMake(self.AnswerView.frame.origin.x , self.AnswerView.frame.origin.y + 300, self.AnswerView.frame.size.width, self.AnswerView.frame.size.height)

    AnswerView.alpha=1.0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations:{
        self.AnswerView.frame = CGRectMake(self.AnswerView.frame.origin.x , self.AnswerView.frame.origin.y - upValue, self.AnswerView.frame.size.width, self.AnswerView.frame.size.height)
    })


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CGFloat` value is too high `1500`. I think your Y position calculation `self.AnswerView.frame.origin.y - upValue` is resulting into negative value making object going out of screen. Print `self.AnswerView.frame` and check the value!

Comment: Sorry...Actually that value for me is 300... I was just trying to change it from 300 -1500. but it remains the same no matter how i change that value

Comment: Try to increase your animation duration.

Comment: Also ensure that there is no constraint on your `AnswerView`.